# IOS: Navigation bar disappears after push segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

[image: stroyboard]

Every time I perform my show(push) segue the articles VC does not have its navigation bar present to display the title or the back button. I have also checked if the navigation controller has a title as that seemed to be the solution to some cases. The class that performs the segue just sends information. Categories is an enumeration.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap your articleVC with another NavigationController.
Or instead of using segue, you can push it with navigation controller to reuse the NavigationBar.

```
let yourArticleViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "articleViewControllerIdentifier") as! ArticleViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourArticleViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Is the View Controller's Identifier the same as the Storyboard ID?

Comment: @Sak6lab It's exactly that one

Comment: Im sorry, what is "that" one? I don't mean to sound rude with that question, if I do.

Comment: No problem, @Sak6lab The Identifier is exactly the Storyboard ID

Comment: Thank you so much @Juan Curti

Comment: Can you provide the same solution with the function prepareForSegue() ? Because I got to use it and the self.navigationController.pushViewController can't work

Answer (score 0):

ArticlesVC should be embedded in its own navigation controller. That should resolve your issue.

[iOS Swift - View Controller - Embedded Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nteZU.jpg)

Comment: Would I be able to go back to the perspective VC?

Comment: @Sak6lab Yes you will be.